# Flurry with react-native

Tags: react-native, flurry

i'm integrating flurry with my react-native app. I use react-native-flurry-sdk@3.7.0 with react-native@0.59.9. I did everything acсording with https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-flurry-sdk, but i couldn't send events. Most of them(events) doesn't received by platform. Only a few part of them reach the target with a big delay(a couple of hours).

This is my flurry settings:

```
import Flurry from "react-native-flurry-sdk";

const FLURRY_ANDROID_API_KEY = "...";
const FLURRY_IOS_API_KEY = "...";

new Flurry.Builder()
  .withCrashReporting(true)
  .withLogEnabled(true)
  .withLogLevel(Flurry.LogLevel.DEBUG)
  .build(FLURRY_ANDROID_API_KEY, FLURRY_IOS_API_KEY);

Flurry.logEvent("1", { param: "true" }, true);
Flurry.endTimedEvent("React Native Timed Event");
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, please see,

- https://github.com/flurry/react-native-flurry-sdk/issues/17
- https://github.com/flurry/react-native-flurry-sdk/issues/19

It has been resolved in 5.3.0 release with the session delay fix.